# Create Excel selective drop-down list with condition (NOT cascaded condition) for Excel 2019

Tags: excel, excel-formula, drop-down-menu, conditional-statements

### **The following **initial situation**:**

I want to create a conditional list from an existing table. I have a 2D-table that contains my condition in the first column and the actual content of the list to be created (still unfiltered) in the second column.

[image: excel2.png]

## **Question:**

**How can I create a conditional list in Excel 2019?**

*Thank you very much for your help!*

## **Target state:**

[image: excel.png]

*The coloured representation only serves the purpose of better comprehensibility and quicker comprehension!*

#### My current status:

I have already searched many supposed solutions for my requirements on the internet, but unfortunately without success so far, as most of them dealt with cascaded lists, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69089998/dropdown-list-with-a-conditional-statement). As I understand it, it's just a loop `[=$A$2:$B$7]` and a conditional `[=IF($A2="1";$B2;"")]`.

*... but unfortunately I haven't found a solution yet that solves this problem for me.*

#### little UPDATE:

I am based on Excel version 2019, I had forgotten to write that, so unfortunately I cannot use any functions from Excel 2021 or Office 356 - such as [FILTER()](https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/office/filter-funktion-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759).
*Sorry for the incomplete requirements or constraints.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A <kbd>FILTER( )</kbd> alternative is <kbd>INDEX( )</kbd> & <kbd>AGGREGATE( )</kbd> or <kbd>SMALL( )</kbd> / <kbd>LARGE( )</kbd>. This uses an auxiliary column to extract the required data, I have taken the condition as `<>` not equal to blank you can use `=1` as well.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$7,AGGREGATE(15,6,
 (ROW($A$2:$A$7)-ROW($A$2)+1)/($A$2:$A$7<>""),ROWS(D$1:D1))),"")
```

---

And fill down as far you need it.

Next create a named range of the range created using the above formula to list in the data validation. Refer the .gif .

---

Another alternative and dynamic way of creating it will be using <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd>

[image]

---

To perform the task using <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd>, follow the steps:

---

- First convert the source range into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table1`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Priority] <> null and [Priority] <> ""),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Item"})
in
    #"Removed Other Columns"
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result. Therefore select a cell in the same worksheet where you want to place it.

---

Now, hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to open the <kbd>DATA VALIDATION</kbd> window --> From <kbd>Settings</kbd> --> Under <kbd>Allow</kbd> click <kbd>List</kbd> --> In Source select the imported table from <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd>. Refer the .gif. Also the data gets updated on a single refresh, which you can automate as well using <kbd>VBA</kbd>

---

### Edit:

To exclude the blanks in the **`Data-Validation`** list you can use the following formula in **`Name Manager`**

```
=$D$2:INDEX($D:$D,COUNTIF($D:$D,"?*"))
```

---

Watch below:

[image]

---

You can download the workbook from **[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2cjkSr92oGLthSDaRR?e=4OY1Tk)**

---

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much for the very detailed instructions @mayukh-bhattacharya :)

Unfortunately, there is still one tiny question to your 1st option: What am I doing wrong that there are still empty lines at the end of my new drop-down list? My “Auxillary Column” (Column D) must be just as long as my original data source (Column A+B), since I only know at "runtime" how many items get a priority.

Comment: @DevArchitectMaster sorry can;t say without a screenshot, can you post a screencap please. Also in your post the screenshot it looks like you have merged cells can you unmerge them. Well if you need both the columns then the formula will be like `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$B$7,AGGREGATE(15,6,
 (ROW($A$2:$A$7)-ROW($A$2)+1)/($A$2:$A$7<>""),ROWS(D$1:D1)),{1,2}}),"")`

Comment: @DevArchitectMaster you can also use `Power Query` here, it will be more easy and not complicated like formulas.

Comment: you are of course right, with a screenshot many things are easy. Which merging of the cells do you mean? The example at D2/E2? That was only for better readability and had no further functional use.

I just wonder how you managed to get your drop-down list to have exactly the number of items and no "empty" entries at the end. For me it looks like this: 

[![Excel.gif](https://i.postimg.cc/CMjjxrkB/Excel.gif)](https://postimg.cc/z3GLdjd8)

Comment: @DevArchitectMaster ah yes that functionality is available only in `MS365` for you it would be different and needs a volatile function. Instead use the `Power Query` it will be dynamic and you dont need volatile functions as well

Comment: @DevArchitectMaster i have made some adjustments you dont need volatile functions also, I am updating the post, while you can download the workbook from **[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2cjkSr92oGLthSDaRR?e=xVaZzK)**

Comment: @DevArchitectMaster I have just updated the post, refer the `.gif`

Comment: **Thank you so much for all your efforts! I am positively stunned.**

For my understanding, I have also reproduced your second possibility. I noticed that the query does not update automatically. This is probably what you meant by "*In addition, the data is updated once, which you can also automate with VBA*". Are VBA scripts the only way to make the query dynamic? --- Thank you also for the completed `workbook`. --- I saw the updated post and immediately tested it on myself. Great idea with the `Name Manager`, I had never worked with it before.

Comment: No with `VBA` i meant about the auto refresh, well there are options to auto refresh using `Power Query` in properties of query see here **[ThisoneabtPQ](https://exceloffthegrid.com/auto-refresh-power-query/#:~:text=To%20implement%20this%3A%201%20From%20the%20ribbon%20select,OK%20to%20close%20the%20Query%20Properties%20dialog%20box.)**

Comment: See when you add new data, it wont directly show in the newly imported table of PQ, once you refresh the imported PQ, it will show, for this refreshing automation you can use VBA, however i think for data validation the list will not be that much that you need vba refresh you can do it manually once in a while. Also ensure if the whole solution has helped you to resolve then click on the tick mark beside to answer to accept it, so it helps someone in the future

Comment: Very thorough. Well explained.

Comment: Hi @P.b , i tried to put in all the possibilities I know. with `FILTER()` it was already shown and wasnt an option.

Comment: May I ask a follow-up question @mayukh-bhattacharya: If I check for two conditions (column A and column C) and would like to connect them with logical AND operator, where do I have to adjust the formula (in column D)? Since my transfer unfortunately did not work successfully. Thank you very much!

Comment: @DevArchitectMaster perhaps you can do like this : `=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$7,AGGREGATE(15,6,
 (ROW($A$2:$A$7)-ROW($A$2)+1)/(($A$2:$A$7<>"")*($C$2:$C$7="Criteria")),ROWS(D$1:D1))),"")`

Comment: @DevArchitectMaster this one see `(($A$2:$A$7<>"")*($C$2:$C$7="Criteria"))` where you need to make changes, simple i think

Comment: perfect many thanks for all your efforts!

Comment: Is it possible that your adjustments (see update above) with the volatile functions only work if the condition is fulfilled at least once? In the download you provided, I was also able to reproduce the error ([![Excel.gif](https://i.postimg.cc/Y90q92yr/Excel.gif)](https://postimg.cc/ZBkhsmS2)). How do I have to select the index here in order to prevent this misbehaviour? Thank you very much.

Comment: @DevArchitectMaster hey sorry for the delay in response. No no I have not shown any with volatile function, `INDEX()` with `AGGREGATE()` is not volatile, Ok I will fix that in the workbook attached

Comment: @DevArchitectMaster well also when there is nothing what should be the output do you need it as blank? Ok check just made changes, when there is nothing, the data validation will not work any more

Comment: no problem, you are welcome. Ah okay then, that was an understanding problem on my part. Your suggestion to disable data validation when not elements are available is a good idea. Unfortunately, an error still occurs on my end. Once the data validation list was empty, the drop-down list deactivates as intended, but it does not reactivate when elements are in the data validation list again. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @DevArchitectMaster see I made an adjustment, if that is the case, i think for helper column we dont need the header anymore. and see the formula i have applied in Name Manager which is also there in column `H`

Comment: ah very good thank you! What else did you change besides the `+1` in the Name Manager so that the empty line is not at the end of the list when there are entries? Because if I reproduce the example for my understanding, I always have an empty row at the end of the list when I add the `+1` in the `index()`.

Comment: nothing else i had done just added `+1` and removed the header and works as per your requirements

Answer (score 0):

You need an intermediate step:

Create a list with filtered values - e.g. on a hidden sheet or next to your base list:
`=FILTER(B2:B7,A2:A7=1)`

[image]

Then you create your validation list like this:

**IMPORTANT**: dont't miss the hash tag at the end of $C$2**#**

[image]

**There is no option to avoid the intermediate step = create a filtered list physically on a sheet.**

Comment: Thank you @Ike very much for your rapid and good solution. Unfortunately, I had forgotten to mention in the requirements that I am using Excel 2019 and therefore cannot use the filter() function. Sorry for the incomplete requirements and constraints. I have corrected the error and added it to the task.

Is there another way to do this without the filter() function for Excel 2019?

Comment: In addition to the answer, since column A contains a number we could choose to omit `=1`: `=FILTER(B2:B7,A2:A7)`