# Creating a combined list with condition (NOT cascaded condition) from two columns to be combined for Excel 2019

Tags: excel, excel-formula, drop-down-menu, conditional-statements

### **Starting Position:**

My [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76867587/create-excel-selective-drop-down-list-with-condition-not-cascaded-condition-fo) here serves as a basis:

> I want to create a conditional list from an existing table. I have a 2D-table that contains my condition in the first column and the actual content of the list to be created (still unfiltered) in the second **and third** column.

This question is now to be expanded to include another requirement:
**How can I create a combined list** (*in `column E`; like `column F`*) **from two separate columns** (*`colum C` + `column B`*) **in `Excel 2019`?**
*The current formula for column E is in `A10`.*

[image: excel.png]

#### My current status:

My current status is based on the answer to the initial question.

`=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$7,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$2:$A$7)-ROW($A$2)+1)/($A$2:$A$7<>""),ROWS(D$1:D1))),"")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Concatenate two separate INDEXes looking at the two columns:

```
=IFERROR(
    INDEX($C$2:$C$7,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$2:$A$7)-ROW($A$2)+1)/($A$2:$A$7<>""),ROWS(D$1:D1)))
    &": "&
    INDEX($B$2:$B$7,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$2:$A$7)-ROW($A$2)+1)/($A$2:$A$7<>""),ROWS(D$1:D1)))
    ,"")
```